# How to sum durations if the according date is below a certain date (Excel)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple excel table where the column A has a date in each of it's cell and column B are durations. I want to write a formula where each cell in B shall be summed, if it meets the criteria, that it is below a certain date (in this example 17.11.2003).

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5;">="&"17.11.2003";B1:B5)
```

The cell that contains the formula is formated like this:

```
[h]:mm;@
```

The formula above works, but the value it calculates is way to high. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to sum when the date is below.
I assume below is an older date.
The condition should be "<"&"17.11.2003" or "<="&"17.11.2003" if you want to include that date.

Comment: Assuming the Windows regional short date settings is `DMY`, `"<17.11.2003"` should work just as well.

Comment: I prefer `<"&DATE(2003; 11; 17)`. Your criteria will be right; you just need to ensure that column A's values are true dates.

Comment: @Jeeped: that's the safest aproach, since it's independent of system settings. I just kept the Op's since he claimed it was working.

Comment: The OP states that *'the value it calculates is way to high'*. That could be because text is being compared to dates or text is being compared to other text. I'm not on a DMY dd.mm.yyyy system but I know there are problems with using them in a computer program originally designed to work with MDY m/d/yy. Always minimize the number of things that can go wrong.

Comment: My answer was on the assumption that "below" is an older date, thus replacing the `>` with `<`. In the sample the day is 17. There is no month 17, so, I think, it would return 0 (zero) on your hypothesis (I tested using an invalid date).

Comment: *'way too high'* is not enough information. Take a look at [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1dn7.png) where I forced text to look like dates in column A and then used true dates in column D. Note default left alignment in column A (text) and default right alignment in column D (dates or numbers).

Comment: Yes, the information is slim. We shouldn't have to guess the OP intent or data. Let's wait for him to clarify.